# Keeping track of continuities

Tags: comics, continuity

I'm trying to get back into marvel comics (specifically, but I'm guessing a more general answer would benefit the masses here) and I'm struggling to pin down which comic lines occur in the same multiverse. Is there some database of all linked comics?

My multiverse, I mean lines of comics. For example, I'd say that Uncanny X-men and Ultimate X-Men have different continuities, and thus different multiverses. They can never cross over.

As an example, I've reccently acquired *Wolverine and the X-men* and *X-force*, both of which contain Wolverine do something different (Running a school vs being part of a ninja-esque task force) at comepletely the same time (as far as I can tell), so it seems unlikely they're from the same multiverse.

How can I keep track of all the continuities?

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not a comics reader but... what is meant by "continuity" here? Maybe I got it, but it seems I'm not able to explain it, so I'll wait for someone's explanation... :P

Comment: @FeralOink No I do mean unlikely, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I'm going to delete my comments, as they aren't relevant after your helpful edit.

Comment: @Alenanno This describes one type of continuity in comics (in general), retrocons http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1110/1591

Comment: @FeralOink Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard, universal way across companies.

Historically, the main Marvel Universe has been [Earth 616](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-616) with alternate timelines (eg: The Days of Future Past timeline) being part of stories within the main books. As confusing as it has been, there have been points in time where a single character was the star of multiple books - where their adventures could not possibly take place concurrently. Spider-Man was the most guilty of this in the Marvel world, in my opinion. I recall him having something like 4 books of his own in the early to mid 90's.

In the past, there was a series called "What If..." where each book was a separate timeline separate from the main timeline and separate from each other. They had no bearing whatsoever on the Earth 616 continuity.

Roughly 10 years ago (maybe closer to 12), the Ultimates timeline was introduced. All of the associated books were titled "Ultimate [character/team name]" to make it easy to distinguish between the "main" continuity and this new set of reboots.

Your question regarding the non-Ultimate Wolverine and X-team books, while valid, makes the false assumption that they are NOT the same timeline. It's always been a little bit confusing as they're published at the same time and sometimes stories cross over from book-to-book, but one must often assume (or more correctly, accept) that certain stories take place before or after another.

When Jim Lee split the X-Men team into X-men and Uncanny X-Men, this was less of an issue as he did so, in part, to give more feature time to all of the characters. With such a huge roster, there was just no way to give attention to everybody's favorite character. But even then, Wolverine, for example already had his own book. It was meant to tell the stories of what he did on his time off from the X-Men, or before his affiliation with them.

Similarly, team books with prominent characters have always had this issue. Captain America, Spider-Man, Iron Man, Batman, Superman, Green Lantern - the list goes on and on. They're all members (at least part time) of groups that have their own comic series - and they all have their own personal books as well.

DC Comics, on the other hand, just relaunched their "New 52" where they simply wiped the slate clean with ALL of their books - not just a select group as with Marvel's "Ultimates". Whether readers like the new changes or not, it certainly does make it easier to keep the difference straight.

Comment: My mistake was to think they all happened at the same time!

Comment: Very easy mistake to make. Often times there are no contextual clues to exactly when something happens.