# Is Beast a Secret Avenger or is he a Vice Principal?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, wolverine-and-the-x-men, avengers

The upcoming Avengers Vs X-men ties in with several different comics lines, namely [Wolverine and the X-Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_and_the_X-Men_(comics)) and [Secret Avengers](http://marvel.com/universe/Secret_Avengers). Beast is listed as a current member of both of these factions.

Now, I am under the [impression](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12953/3804) that not all Marvel Comics stories occur simultaneously on reading. How does this factor in to Beast's allegiances? Is this something already decided (e.g. he leaves sometime after the current WatX story line, but before AvX) or is it undecided?

I can't understand how he can be on both 'teams' if you will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, he's both.

Secret Avengers has been going on for a while now, so it definitely doesn't happen after AvX.  And Wolverine and the X-Men is happening before AvX as well, since there will be AvX tie-ins soon.

The complex relationship between when a comic is published and when it occurs chronologically is often confusing, such as with Spider-Island and Wonder Man's assault on the Avengers.  In this case, it's very simple.  Beast works at the Jean Grey School for Higher Learning during the day and moonlights as a Secret Avenger whenever he is called on by Steve Rogers.

In the conflict between the Avengers and the X-Men, my assumption is that Beast will definitely NOT be on the X-Men side.  Since Cyclops is leading the fight against the Avengers, it seems unlikely Beast will find his cause sympathetic, due to their recent falling-out.

Answer (score -3):

The Beast was one of the original X Men back in the 60's, at which time he was drawn as simply a human with distinctly Neanderthal features, tremendous physical strength, though nothing to equal heroes like Spiderman, the Thing, or the Hulk, and extreme speed and agility. Hank McCoy left  the X Men team to take a research job (I can't remember where) and while there, he became exposed to a process designed to mutate normal humans. His blue fur and other animal like features are the result of "mutating a mutant."

It was a good while later that he became involved with the Avengers.

Comment: Hi, White Avenger. That's some great back ground on Beast. But I don't think that helps answer the current question, unfortunately.